# How to reduce caption font in \subcaption for a particular figure

Tags: beamer, subcaption

How to reduce a font size of a particular figure in `\subfigure` environment in beamer. I know how to reduce the caption font *globally* `\usepackage[font=small]{subcaption}`, but I am looking for a font size handling *locally*.

I am showing four subfigures in one frame using `\subfigure` from `\subcaption` package. The problem is the subfigure's individual captions, **(a), (b), (c), (d)**,  are way too big as compared to the labeling text which is used inside the sub-pictures. 
So, if I increase the individual subfigure height using `\begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}` then the four pictures go out of page, if I decrease the size of it then font which is used inside the figure becomes too small as compared to the caption.
So, I want to decrease the caption font so that with respect to text used inside the picture will not look bad.

My MWE
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {

% The Beamer class comes with a number of default slide themes
% which change the colors and layouts of slides. Below this is a list
% of all the themes, uncomment each in turn to see what they look like.

%\usetheme{default}
%\usetheme{AnnArbor}
%\usetheme{Antibes}
%\usetheme{Bergen}
%\usetheme{Berkeley}
%\usetheme{Berlin}
%\usetheme{Boadilla}
%\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
%\usetheme{Copenhagen}
%\usetheme{Darmstadt}
%\usetheme{Dresden}
%\usetheme{Frankfurt}
%\usetheme{Goettingen}
%\usetheme{Hannover}
%\usetheme{Ilmenau}
%\usetheme{JuanLesPins}
%\usetheme{Luebeck}
% \usetheme{Madrid}
%\usetheme{Malmoe}
%\usetheme{Marburg}
%\usetheme{Montpellier}
%\usetheme{PaloAlto}
%\usetheme{Pittsburgh}
%\usetheme{Rochester}
%\usetheme{Singapore}
%\usetheme{Szeged}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

% As well as themes, the Beamer class has a number of color themes
% for any slide theme. Uncomment each of these in turn to see how it
% changes the colors of your current slide theme.
\useoutertheme{infolines}
%\usecolortheme{albatross}
%\usecolortheme{beaver}
%\usecolortheme{beetle}
%\usecolortheme{crane}
%\usecolortheme{dolphin}
%\usecolortheme{dove}
%\usecolortheme{fly}
%\usecolortheme{lily}
%\usecolortheme{orchid}
%\usecolortheme{rose}
%\usecolortheme{seagull}
%\usecolortheme{seahorse}
%%\usecolortheme{whale}
%\usecolortheme{wolverine}

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %

% % % Black Background Configuration
%\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white,bg=black!90}
%\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=white}
%
%\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red!85!black}
%
%\setbeamercolor{item projected}{use=item,fg=black,bg=item.fg!35}
%
%\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg}
%\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!95!black}
%\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!90!black}
%\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!95!black,bg=black!80}
%
%\setbeamercolor*{framesubtitle}{fg=white}
%
%\setbeamercolor*{block title}{parent=structure,bg=black!60}
%\setbeamercolor*{block body}{fg=black,bg=black!10}
%\setbeamercolor*{block title alerted}{parent=alerted text,bg=black!15}
%\setbeamercolor*{block title example}{parent=example text,bg=black!15}

% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %

%\setbeamertemplate{footline} % To remove the footer line in all slides uncomment this line
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number] % To replace the footer line in all slides with a simple slide count uncomment this line

%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line
}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

%\usepackage{IEEEtrantools.sty} %Copy file IEEEtran.sty to folder where miktek is installed i-e E:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\IEEEtran.sty
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools} %For TexLive

\usepackage{comment}
%\bibliography{references}
%\usepackage{bibentry}

%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage[disable,colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
%\usepackage[obeyDraft,colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty 
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} %for slide transition
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered] %To achieve numbering of figures, you need to set.



\begin{document}

%-----------------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}
        %           \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{f22.eps}
        \caption{ }
        \label{fig7a}
    \end{subfigure} 
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}
        %           \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{f23.eps}
        \caption{ }
        \label{fig7b}
    \end{subfigure} \\%
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}
%       \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{f24.eps}
        \caption{ }
        \label{fig7c}
    \end{subfigure} %
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}
        %           \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{f25.eps}
        \caption{ }
        \label{fig7d}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{\textbf{My caption}
    \label{f7}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please make your example to a MWE? By removing all the unnecessary lines in the preable you will make it much more clearer. Furthermore, you do not need `graphicx` in beamer, beamer itself already provides it. There is no need for placement options like `[h!]` in a class without floating elements like `beamer`. Finally there is a missing `}` after "my caption".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would add the instruction

```
\captionsetup[subfigure]{font=scriptsize,labelfont=scriptsize}
```

after `\begin{figure}`. That way, the setup change is local to this particular `figure` environment.

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[disable,colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty 
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} 
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{font=scriptsize,labelfont=scriptsize}
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{f22.eps}
        \caption{Hello World}
        \label{fig7a}
    \end{subfigure} \hspace*{\fill}
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{f23.eps}
        \caption{Good Morning}
        \label{fig7b}
    \end{subfigure} 

    \begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{f24.eps}
        \caption{Good Night}
        \label{fig7c}
    \end{subfigure} \hspace*{\fill}
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{f25.eps}
        \caption{Goodbye World}
        \label{fig7d}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{\textbf{My caption}}
    \label{f7}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If you want the overall figure caption to show up in the frame, you must reduce the sizes of the images, maybe along the lines of the following example.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{beamer} % remove 'demo' option in real document

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[disable,colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty 
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} 
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=scriptsize,
                      textfont={scriptsize,bf}}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont=scriptsize,
                         textfont=scriptsize}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth,height=0.2\textheight,keepaspectratio]{f22.eps}
    \caption{Hello World}
    \label{fig7a}
    \end{subfigure} \qquad
    \begin{subfigure}{.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth,height=0.2\textheight,keepaspectratio]{f23.eps}
    \caption{Good Morning}
    \label{fig7b}
    \end{subfigure} 

    \begin{subfigure}{.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth,height=0.2\textheight,keepaspectratio]{f24.eps}
    \caption{Good Night}
    \label{fig7c}
    \end{subfigure} \qquad
    \begin{subfigure}{.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth,height=0.2\textheight,keepaspectratio]{f25.eps}
    \caption{Goodbye World}
    \label{fig7d}
    \end{subfigure}

\caption{My caption}
\label{f7}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How to do the same to reduce the font size of the caption of the four subfigures.

Comment: @kaka - Not sure I understand your comment. `scriptsize` represents a 30% linear reduction in the font size. Are you asking how the font size might be reduced even further?

Comment: I mean how to reduce the size of `\caption{\textbf{My caption}}` in above code. It is also not visible in the frame.

Comment: Ah, you mean the caption of the figure, not of the subfigures. How about `\captionsetup[figure]{font=scriptsize,labelfont=scriptsize}`? Incidentally, the figure caption isn't visible because the images are too large, crowding out some of the other material. I would reduce both the widths and the heights of the images.

Answer (score 2):

Redefining `\thesubfigure` and restoring it to normal font size afterwards gives the desired results:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{infolines}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered] 

\captionsetup{font=bf}

\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\normalfont(\alph{subfigure})}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \begin{figure}[h!]
            \begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}
                \renewcommand\thesubfigure{\fontsize{5}{8}\selectfont (\alph{subfigure})}
                \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{pic}
                \caption{ }
                \label{fig7a}
                \renewcommand\thesubfigure{\normalfont (\alph{subfigure})}
            \end{subfigure} 
            \begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}
                \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{pic}
                \caption{ }
                \label{fig7b}
            \end{subfigure}
            \caption{My caption}
            \label{f7}
        \end{figure}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Remarks**

- no need for `graphicx` in `beamer`, `beamer` itself already provides it
- also no need for placement options like `[h!]` in `beamer`, as `beamer` disables floating mechanism.

Comment: thanks. It helps. I accept Mico's answer, as it is more easy for me to understand.